# Image uploader from http://dondedeportes.es/uploader-previewer/: Change input to take multiple requests

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working with an image uploader from the [SITE](http://dondedeportes.es/uploader-previewer/) in the title. This image uploader generates several forms with its respective iframe for inputs.

I am trying to eliminate this separate inputs and have only one input that will take multiple uploads(at least up to 4). I spoke with the author and only receive an answer of modifying the uploaderPreviewer.js and I get can what I want accomplished.

How can I modify the js file to have it generate one input that will take multiple file uploads(at least up to 4)?

If you like to take a full look at the js file: [HERE](http://webprolearner2346.zxq.net/imageupload/js/uploaderPreviewer.js)

**Construct Form**

```
jQuery.uploaderPreviewer = new Object({
    formsCount: 1, // number of image forms to handle
    allowedImageTypes: new Array('png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'),
    uploadImageAjaxUrl: 'php/uploadImage.php',
    removeImageAjaxUrl: 'php/removeImage.php',
    uploadsThumbDir: 'uploads/thumb/',
    messages: {
        imageLabel: 'Image',
        fileTypeError: 'The file is not an allowed type.',
        removeButtonCaption: 'remove',
        removeButtonTitle: 'Remove the image'
    }
});
```

**Public Function**

```
jQuery.uploaderPreviewer.createImageForms = function(options) {

    $.extend(this, options);

    var forms = '';

    for(var i=1; i <= this.formsCount; i++) {
        forms += createImageForm(i);
    }    
    return configureImageForms($(forms));
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using another script, I would suggest this one. Been using it on other projects, only downside with it is has some minor incompatibility with previous IE version (drag-drop).

```
https://github.com/valums/file-uploader/
```

Answer (score 1):

Try ajaxSubmit feature from http://jquery.malsup.com/form plugin. I have tried it and it's work fine for me in every browser I have tested (Ie7)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the HTML5 `input[multiple]` attribute.